# toggleClass() only toggling to one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having trouble with a jQuery/Angular function being executed on click.

```
<a ng-click="like()" href="#" class="like like--yes"></a>
```

Basically, when a click occurs on a like button, I want to toggle the like--yes and the like--no classes. I've inspected the DOM while clicking, and once it has been set to like--no, it refuses to change back.

```
$scope.like = function() {
    $('.like--no').toggleClass('like--no like--yes');
    $('.like--yes').toggleClass('like--yes like--no');
}
```

I need two different functions so to speak, as I'm adding different animations depending on whether it's a like/unlike.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? There's more to it, but I've stripped some of the unnecessary code out for clarity.

Thanks.

Comment: toggleClass function adds or removes a class it doesn't swithes between them

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using AngularJS so instead of using jQuery, why not use ngClass?

Like this:

```
    <a ng-click="toggleLike()" ng-class="{'like--yes': like, 'like--no': !like}">Hello World!</a>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Onb8L63nZf1txAYa77i?p=preview)

Comment: I'm still learning how to use Angular. I'll look into ng-class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.like').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('like--no like--yes');
    if($(this).text() == 'like'){
        $(this).text('unlike');
    }else{
         $(this).text('like');
    }
});
```

and html

```
<a href="#" class="like like--yes">like</a>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bureyhdz/2/)

Comment: I need two separate functions. One for liking, another for unliking. The reason for this is because I have two different animations – a like results in a pulse animation, an unlike results in a fadeOut.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a logical issue

```
$scope.like = function() {
    $('.like--no').toggleClass('like--no like--yes');
    $('.like--yes').toggleClass('like--yes like--no');
}
```

Case:- first line changes like--no to like--yes and after that second line changes like--yes to like-- no again.

You should try .hasClass() function to check whether element has class then use toggle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the second line is overwritting the first one.

It sets the class to `like--yes` and the second line catches the `like--yes` and set it to `like--no` everytime.

Try something like:

```
$scope.like = function() {
    if( $('.like').hasClass( 'like--yes' ) ) {
       $('.like').removeClass( 'like--yes' );
       $('.like').addClass( 'like--no' );
    } else {
        $('.like').removeClass('like--no');
        $('.like').addClass('like--yes');
    }
}
```

Maybe you need change `$('.link')` to `$(this)` to get the actually clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally frown upon to deal with DOM jQuery-style inside an Angular's controller, which is what you attempted to do and the other answers suggested.

Just have a variable that reflects the `like` state (you can set it directly in the View or inside the `$scope.like()` function and use `ng-class` to toggle the class:

```
<a ng-click="like=!like" href="#" ng-class="like ? 'like--yes':'like--no'"></a>
```